# Comment out code block in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, comments, canopy

In emacs you can highlight a section and select a menu function to prepend a "#" to every line in the selection. I am trying to give up my emacs addiction and use the IDE in Canopy but can't find this functionality. Is it missing or am I just having trouble finding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "Toggle Block Comment" in the Edit Menu (with platform-specific shortcut).

Comment: On my platform the shortcut is Cntrl+/